# implementing client side filtering using react

Tags: reactjs

I have built a small application of adding and deleting items using React, i wanted to implement search filter in the application after user enters some items and display only those items which user search, otherwise display all items,

Code can be found here

https://codesandbox.io/s/search-filter-uobil

Comment: you forgot to ask a question :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression and filter the results you want like this:

```
    const filterItems = e => {
    let matchesFilter = new RegExp(e.target.value.trim(), 'i')
    const item = props.allOptions.filter(item => 
         matchesFilter.test(item)
      )
    console.log(item)
  }
```

see [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/search-filter-40ng8?file=/src/options.js:88-331)

Edit: I've updated the sandbox to reflect what you wanted in the comments. I'm using hooks but what is important is that the function will filter the incoming allOptions based on a filter that you set in the input text field.

Comment: its working, but how do i render those filtered items now?

Comment: now the item holds all the matched items, how do i loop through that item array to render